# Linq query with nested Order By?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi there I have the following class structure:

```cs
class Apple
{
    public IEnumerable<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }
}

class Banana
{
    public IEnumerable<Carrot> Carrots { get; set; }
}

class Carrot
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

class Dog
{
    public string Target { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to query all from a collection of Type Apple where Apples.Bananas.Carrots.Dogs.Target matches my input. I currently have.

```cs
var result = Apples.Where(apple => 
            apple.Bananas.Any(banana => 
                banana.Carrots.Any(carrort => carrort.Dogs.Any(dog => 
                    dog.Target.Equals(input)))));
```

My difficulty is I now realize I only want the newest entry from the Carrots list.

I have not been able to figure out how to order the carrots by DateCreated descending and take first within this query.

I have tried the following but its throwing and exception:

```cs
var result = Apples.Where(apple =>
    apple.Bananas.Any(banana =>
        banana.Carrots.OrderByDescending(carrot =>
            carrot.DateCreated).First().Dogs.Any(dog =>
                dog.Target.Equals(input))));
```

Exception `Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException`

Comment: Whatever this Antlr exception is, it's (almost certainly) not related to your linq query.

Comment: I'd separate each of these into separate steps. (That's redundant. I'd separate these into steps.)

Comment: If you only want the newest carrot, doesn't that mean that out of all the carrots you'll only want one, and only one banana has that carrot, and only one apple has that banana, so you'd want the result to be a single apple?

Comment: As other comments note, the exception is not coming from any code you've shown us.  **Your best bet is to produce a small, clear, complete program that we can run**. By producing such a program, you will either find your problem, or you'll make a program that is small enough for others to understand the problem. The problem almost certainly has nothing to do with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ever unsure about your LINQ query, by all means, you should simplify it. Remember, LINQ will continue to return IEnumerable until you ask for an object (First, ToArray, ToList, etc.). Therefore, there's no harm in simplifying the code in the name of simplicity and debugging.

```
var ohGodMyEyes = Apples
   .Where(apple => apple.Bananas
       .Any(banana => banana.Carrots
           .OrderByDescending(carrot => carrot.DateCreated)));

var result = ohGodMyEyes
    .First().Dogs
    .Any(dog => dog.Target.Equals(input));
```